# Prove that $(I+J)^{m}= I^{m}+\big(\Sigma _{k=1}^{m-1}I^{m-k}J^k\big)+J^m$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification, commutative-algebra, ideals

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I,J$ two ideals. Then $(I+J)^{m}= I^{m}+\big(\Sigma _{k=1}^{m-1}I^{m-k}J^k\big)+J^m$ for every natural $m\geq 2$.

---

I want to confirm that my proof is correct.

It's easy to see that it's true for $m=2$. Suppose that it's also true for a natural $m\geq 2$. Then

$(I+J)^{m+1}=(I+J)^m(I+J)=(I+J)^mI+(I+J)^mJ=$

$\big[I^{m}+\big(\Sigma _{k=1}^{m-1}I^{m-k}J^k\big)+J^m\big]I+\big[I^{m}+\big(\Sigma _{k=1}^{m-1}I^{m-k}J^k\big)+J^m\big]J=$

$I^{m+1}+\big(\Sigma_{k=1}^{m-1}I^{m-k}J^k\big)I+J^mI+I^mJ+\big(\Sigma_{k=1}^{m-1}I^{m-k}J^k\big)J+J^{m+1}=$

$I^{m+1}+\big[\big(\Sigma_{k=1}^{m-1}I^{m+1-k}J^k\big)+IJ^m
\big]+\big[I^mJ+\big(\Sigma_{k=1}^{m-1}I^{m-k}J^{k+1}\big)\big]+J^{m+1}=$

$I^{m+1}+\big(\Sigma_{k=1}^{\color{red}m}I^{m+1-k}J^k\big)+\big(\Sigma_{k=\color{red}0}^{m-1}I^{m-k}J^{k+1}\big)+J^{m+1}=I^{m+1}+\big(\Sigma_{k=1}^{m}I^{m+1-k}J^k\big)+J^{m+1}$

since $\Sigma_{k=0}^{m-1}I^{m-k}J^{k+1}=\Sigma_{k=1}^{m}I^{m+1-k}J^k$.

So using induction we finish the proof.

---

**My question is:** Did I make any mistake?

Thank you for your attention!

Comment: Writing $(I+J)^m=\sum_{k=0}^mI^{m-k}J^k$ probably clarifies the proof.

Comment: @KentaS I don't want to define $I^0$ for any ideal!

Comment: $I^0=R$, it's the ideal generated by empty products of elements $I$ and the empty product equals $1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. If you wanted to, you could explicitly say where you used the commutativity hypothesis of $R$, but I think it’s clear enough so that you don’t have to.

You were right in formulating the problem as

$$(I+J)^m = I^m +\left(\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} I^{m-k}J^k\right) + J^m$$

because if you set $I^0=R$ (which is natural) and tried proving

$$(I+J)^m =\sum_{k=0}^m I^{m-k}J^k,$$

then this statement is actually *false*.

The reason is because if $R$ does not have an identity, the set of ideals under standard multiplication $(I(R),\cdot)$ is not necessarily a monoid anymore—$R$ no longer acts as the identity element.

For example, setting $R=2\mathbb Z$ and $I=J=R$ considered as ideals of $R$, the conjecture implies
$$R =(I+J)^1 = (I^0J^1 + I^1J^0) = R^2 + R^2 = R^2.$$

However, $R= 2\mathbb Z$ but $R^2= 4\mathbb Z$ is a contradiction.